# How can I render a pageuid in another page?

Tags: fluid, typo3-8.x

I have ready pages and want to render the content of a ready page in an slide down element on an overview page. How can I render the page with uid in a viewhelper without header & footer?

Tried already many options, but mostly:

```
<f:format.raw>{page35}</f:format.raw>
```

or

```
<v:content.render column="0" limit="10" pageUid="35" as="contentElements"></v:content.render>
```

This is the part of the code:

```
<div class="row" id="content">
        <div class="col-md-15">
            <a href="#proj1"><f:format.raw>{content6}</f:format.raw></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-15">
            <a href="#proj2"><f:format.raw>{content7}</f:format.raw></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-15 mh285 bg285">
            <a href="#proj3"><f:format.raw>{content8}</f:format.raw></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-15">
            <a href="#proj4"><f:format.raw>{content9}</f:format.raw></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-15">
            <a href="#proj5"><f:format.raw>{content10}</f:format.raw></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 expandable" id="proj1">
            <f:format.raw>{page48}</f:format.raw>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 expandable" id="proj2">
            <v:content.render column="0" limit="10" pageUid="35" as="contentElements"></v:content.render>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 expandable" id="proj3">
            <f:format.raw>{page49}</f:format.raw>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 expandable" id="proj4">
            <f:format.raw>{page53}</f:format.raw>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 expandable" id="proj5">
            <f:format.raw>{page35}</f:format.raw>
        </div>
</div>

<f:format.raw>{page35}</f:format.raw>
```

shows nothing

and

```
<v:content.render column="0" limit="10" pageUid="35" as="contentElements"></v:content.render>
```

shows an php error